# Why can't I evaluate this integral and obtain a closed-form solution?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation, special-functions

I have the following spherical density distribution:

$\rho(x, z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}\left(1+\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\right)^2}$

which I have broken into a "line of sight" dimension $z$ and a "transverse" dimension $x$. Integrating this profile along the line of sight gives the projected 2d density $\Sigma$:

$\Sigma(x) = 2\int_0^\infty\rho(x,z)dz$

I wish to compute this for any generic upper bound $\zeta$, i.e.

$\Sigma(x; \zeta) = 2\int_0^\zeta\rho(x,z)dz$

(that is, $\zeta=\infty$ corresponds to the case of projecting the entire distribution to the transverse plane, while $\zeta<\infty$ corresponds to a projection which is truncated in the $z$-dimension).

It turns out this has to be solved piecewise; the solution for $x>1$, via Mathematica 11.3, is

$$ \left.\int_0^\zeta\rho(x, z)dz\right\rvert_{x>1}
   = \frac{\zeta \left(\sqrt{x^2+\zeta^2}-1\right)}{\left(x^2-1\right) \left(x^2+\zeta^2-1\right)}+\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\zeta}{\sqrt{\left(x^2-1\right) \left(x^2+\zeta^2\right)}}\right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\zeta}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)}{\left(x^2-1\right)^{3/2}}$$

However, I am unable to obtain the solution for the case $x<1$. I currently only have access to Mathematica 12.0, rather than 11.3, and it is failing on this integral for both cases, even the one above. Performing

```
Assuming[{x < 1, ζ ∈ Reals, ζ > 0}, 
         FullSimplify[Integrate[1/(Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] (1 + Sqrt[x^2 + z^2])^2), {z, 0, ζ}]]]
```

returns a HyperGeometric function, though I suspect that the $x<1$ case should not be much more complicated than $x>1$. Can anyone confirm? Or see any issue?

Comment: Just do indefinite integration very fast. With version 8.0 you don't need any assumptions to get  `mint[x_, z_] = 
 Integrate[1/(Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] (1 + Sqrt[x^2 + z^2])^2), z] `   the result `(Sqrt[-1 + x^2]
   z (-1 + Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]) - (-1 + x^2 + z^2) ArcTan[z/
   Sqrt[-1 + x^2]] + (-1 + x^2 + z^2) ArcTan[z/(
   Sqrt[-1 + x^2] Sqrt[x^2 + z^2])])/((-1 + x^2)^(
 3/2) (-1 + x^2 + z^2)) ` . Since mint[x,0]==0, your definte integral is `mint[x, \[Zeta]] ` .(only not defined at x==0)

Comment: (only not defined at x==0 AND z==1

Answer (score 2):

Beside @user64494 answer, which is valid for `0<x<1 && 0<ζ < Sqrt[1 - x^2]`, there is another solution (Mathematica v12) valid for `0<x<1 &&  ζ >= Sqrt[1 - x^2]`:

```
Integrate[1/(Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] (1 + Sqrt[x^2 + z^2])^2), {z, 0, ζ}, 
Assumptions -> x < 1 && x >= 0 && ζ >= Sqrt[1 - x^2]]
(*ConditionalExpression[(ζ (-1 + Sqrt[x^2 + ζ^2]))/((-1 + x^2) 
(-1 + x^2 + ζ^2)) + (I ArcTanh[ζ/Sqrt[1 - x^2]])/(-1 +x^2)^(3/2)-
(I ArcTanh[ζ/Sqrt[-(-1 + x^2) (x^2 + ζ^2)]])/(-1 + x^2)^(3/2),x>0]*)
```

Comment: The option `Assumptions -> x < 1 && x >= 0 && \[Zeta] >= Sqrt[1 - x^2]` exhausts all the possibilities.

Comment: @user64494 No you need both conditions mentioned in my answer to describe the case `0<x<1`

Comment: Ulrich Neumann (@ does not work): The condition `\[Zeta] >= Sqrt[1 - x^2]` is more general than your `\[Zeta] > Sqrt[1 - x^2] `. Hope I am clear now.

Comment: @user64494 (@ works if you remove the blancs "@UlrichNeumann") You're right, but Mathematica doesn't evaluate the case `\[Zeta] = Sqrt[1 - x^2]`

Comment: Ulrich Neumann: Don't understand you. the command `Integrate[
 1/(Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] (1 + Sqrt[x^2 + z^2])^2), {z, 0, \[Zeta]}, 
 Assumptions -> x < 1 && x >= 0 && \[Zeta] >= Sqrt[1 - x^2]]` performs `ConditionalExpression[(\[Zeta] (-1 + Sqrt[x^2 + \[Zeta]^2]))/((-1 + 
     x^2) (-1 + x^2 + \[Zeta]^2)) + (
  I ArcTanh[\[Zeta]/Sqrt[1 - x^2]])/(-1 + x^2)^(3/2) - (
  I ArcTanh[\[Zeta]/Sqrt[-(-1 + x^2) (x^2 + \[Zeta]^2)]])/(-1 + x^2)^(
  3/2), x > 0]`.Your words "@ works if you remove the blancs @UlrichNeumann" do not correspond to reality.

Comment: My "reality"  might  be found in help " Spaces are not valid in comment reply names, so don't use "@peter smith", always enter it as @peters or @petersmith"

Comment: Your assumptions contain `x<1`, and yet your conditional expression that is returned exists on `x>1`. Unless I'm missing something? The denominator at the end of the final term isn't real for `x<1`.

Comment: Woops, I read that wrong, the conditions don't contradict. My point stands about the imaginary denominator `(x^2-1)^(3/2)`

Answer (score 1):

The following works in 12.0:

```
Integrate[1/(Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] (1 + Sqrt[x^2 + z^2])^2), {z, 0, ζ}, 
 Assumptions -> x < 1 && x >= 0 && ζ > 0]
(*ConditionalExpression[(ζ (-1 + Sqrt[x^2 + ζ^2]))/((-1 + 
 x^2) (-1 + x^2 + ζ^2)) -  ArcTan[ζ/Sqrt[-1 + x^2]]/(-1 + x^2)^(3/2) + 
  ArcTan[ζ/Sqrt[(-1 + x^2) (x^2 + ζ^2)]]/(-1 + x^2)^(3/2), 
ζ < 1 && 0 < x < Sqrt[1 - ζ^2]]*)
```

Comment: Hmm, did this take a while to run, or? Mine runs for a few minutes before spitting the `Integrate` call back to me.

Comment: @Anonymous: It takes 36.3935 s on my old comp.

Comment: Hang on, this answer turns out to be identical to the x>1 case... indeed, this returns an imaginary answer for x<1 (the denominator at the end of the final term isn't real)

Comment: @Anonymous: You are not right, e.g. `ConditionalExpression[(\[Zeta] (-1 + Sqrt[x^2 + \[Zeta]^2]))/((-1 + 
        x^2) (-1 + x^2 + \[Zeta]^2)) - 
   ArcTan[\[Zeta]/Sqrt[-1 + x^2]]/(-1 + x^2)^(3/2) + 
   ArcTan[\[Zeta]/
      Sqrt[(-1 + x^2) (x^2 + \[Zeta]^2)]]/(-1 + x^2)^(3/2), \[Zeta] < 
    1 && 0 < x < Sqrt[1 - \[Zeta]^2]] /. {x -> 1/2, \[Zeta] -> 0.1}` performs `0.0879209 + 0. I`. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: ah, yes, my mistake... I was testing it for cases where $\zeta>1$, and specifically $x > \sqrt{1 - \zeta^2}$. Why are those conditions necessary? I really need a form for which $\zeta$ is unrestricted (in fact, $\zeta$ is eventually replaced by a term $\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$, where $R$ is a constant for which $x\leq R$)

Comment: @Anonymous! You wrote " I really need a form for which ζ is unrestricted", Combine both the results (Ulrich Neumann and me) to this end, e.g. `ConditionalExpression[(\[Zeta] (-1 + Sqrt[x^2 + \[Zeta]^2]))/((-1 + 
        x^2) (-1 + x^2 + \[Zeta]^2)) + (I ArcTanh[\[Zeta]/
        Sqrt[1 - x^2]])/(-1 + x^2)^(3/
       2) - (I ArcTanh[\[Zeta]/
        Sqrt[-(-1 + x^2) (x^2 + \[Zeta]^2)]])/(-1 + x^2)^(3/2), 
  x > 0] /. {x -> 1/3, \[Zeta] -> 5.1} ` produces `0.963313 + 0. I`.

Comment: Genius, thanks so much

Comment: So-called @Anonymous:  the pleasure is all mine.